# Mouseevent div cover div on chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, gantt-chart

I have a gantt chart in d3.js gantt chart. I use a scroll and zoom gantt chart: http://codepen.io/Pau/pen/FKzEa

But I have problem. This is my modification: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgVdgm I want add mouseevent (simple alert) when user mouse over line or tasks. But this doesen't work. I added this events to line and tasks:

```
        svg.select(".gantt-chart-canvas").append("line").attr(
          {
          "class":"verticalDeadLine",
          "x1" : x(testDate),
          "y1" : 0,
          "x2" : x(testDate),
          "y2" : height,
          "fill" : "none",
          "shape-rendering" : "crispEdges",
          "stroke" : "red",
          "z-index" : "550",
          "stroke-width" : "2px"
      }).on('mouseover', function(event) {
            alert("abcd");
        })
        .on('mouseout', function() {

      });
```

I think problem is in this line where added rect, class pane

```
chart.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "pane")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height-margin.top-margin.bottom)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
```

pane in css class:

```
.pane {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

and this div cover line and tasks mousevents.

Mouseevent over line and tasks work, when I change in class pane: `pointer-events: all;` to `pointer-events: auto;`

But after this change, my zoom and scroll not work...

How to change it? I want to zoom-scroll on chart and mousevents on line and tasks work both. I think I must change in line class pointer-events property. But how?

Summary, simpler example. I have two class.

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
    </div">
</div">
```

Both class have mousevent, But class A cover class B. How to set that both mousevents work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first change:

make the `fill` `transparent` from `none`

```
.pane {
  cursor: move;
  fill: transparent;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Second change make the rectangle above `.gantt-chart` class `group`

Like this:

```
var chart = d3.select("body")
                  .append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "chart")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
var drw = chart.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "pane")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height-margin.top-margin.bottom)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
 //now append ganttchart group
var svg = chart.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "gantt-chart")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height-margin.top-margin.bottom)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
```

working code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKBpNm?editors=0010)

hope this helps!